# Update values based on sequence of rows - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
u_a_id      d_c_s       c_nm                        c_v     c_se  line_num
19          878         Test Code - Individual      CO      1     30
19          878         Test Code - Individual      PR      1     31
19          878         Test Code - Individual      PR      2     32
19          878         Test Code - Individual      CO      2     33

19          878         Test Code - Individual      CO      1     33
19          878         Test Code - Individual      PR      1     34
19          878         Test Code - Individual      PR      2     35
19          878         Test Code - Individual      CO      2     36
19          878         Test Code - Individual      PR      3     37
19          878         Test Code - Individual      CO      3     38
```

For each u_a_id, order by line_num, I need to identify if combination of c_nm and c_se is repeated. If the combination is repeated, then I need to update the following based on the sequence:

- d_c_s to 12000 for First
- d_c_s to 12001 for Second
- d_c_s to 12002 for Third
- Append First to c_nm
- Append Second to c_nm
- Append Third to c_nm

The output would look like:

```
u_a_id      d_c_s       c_nm                                c_v     c_se  line_num
19          12000       Test Code, First - Individual       CO      1     30
19          12001       Test Code, Second - Individual      PR      1     31
19          12000       Test Code, First - Individual       PR      2     32
19          12001       Test Code, Second - Individual      CO      2     33

19          12000       Test Code, First - Individual       CO      1     33
19          12001       Test Code, Second - Individual      PR      1     34
19          12000       Test Code, First - Individual       PR      2     35
19          12001       Test Code, Second - Individual      CO      2     36
19          12000       Test Code, First - Individual       PR      3     37
19          12001       Test Code, Second - Individual      CO      3     38
```

Is there anyway in SQL to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is more like this:

select . . .,

```
       (12000 - 1 + seqnum) as d_c_s,
       replace(c_nm, ' - ',
               (case seqnum
                     when 1 then ', First - '
                     when 2 then ', Second - '
                     when 3 then ', Third - '
                     else ' - '
                end)
               ) as c_nm
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c_nm, c_se order by line_num) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by c_nm, c_se) as cnt  
      from t 
     ) t
```

Comment: I think you need to throw `u_a_id` in `partition by` too, based on the problem description. And the OP seems to be looking for an `update` (or `merge`) rather than just `select`.